# REST: The same resource accessed from two different URLs

Tags: rest, url

I've just started my journey with REST, so please be patient while anserwing my questions.

I have some doubts how to cope with some situations. For instance, I read that evenry resource/entity should have its own, unique URL. But how to deal with examples like:

1. There is a list of objects.
2. Each object is described by some basic information and its state.
3. Basic info for object is for example its shape, color.
4. The state of object contains information like position in space, velocity etc.
5. Both two pieces of information (basic + state) are rather big objects (only examplary properties were introduced).

Now, we have the following questions:

1. Get all basic info about objects.
2. Get all object states.
3. Get basic info of object with ID=2.
4. Get state of object ID=5.
5. Get all info of object ID=7.

I tried to solve it in this way:

1. /rest/objects
2. /rest/states
3. /rest/objects/2/basic
4. /rest/objects/5/state (/rest/states/5)
5. /rest/objects/7

However, I've some doubts pointed in 4 - it doesn't look like to be correct. There are two ways to access the same information/resource/entity.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the "basic" just part of the resource? It seems not from your description, but you should consider it. In fact, all of "basic" and "state" might just be part of the resource. It's difficult to be authoritative without more information. For instance, how large is "rather big"?

It also doesn't seem like `/state` should be an independent endpoint, since a state is an integral part of an object, not something that lives on its own.

I might start with something like:

```
1. GET /objects
2. GET /objects?expand=state
3. GET /objects/2?expand=basic -- or -- GET /objects/2/basic
4. GET /objects/5?expand=state -- or -- GET /objects/5/state
5. GET /objects/7?expand=basic,state
```

If you *need* `/state` to be top level, then you have two options:

```
2. GET /states -- or -- GET /objects/states
```

Neither of those are really ideal. It is acceptable to have multiple paths to get to the same resource, as long as there's only one canonical URI for the resource. The issue is that it's harder for the end user to learn APIs that lean heavily on that style. The second style is also confusing. `/objects/XXX` is a specific object, unless `XXX == states`? That's a special case for your end user to have to remember.

Answer (score 0):

From a caching point of view it makes sense to have "state" and "basic" in separate resources - "state" resources changes frequently and is thus non-cachable and "basic" changes seldom and should thus be cachable for a long time. If this is your goal, then go ahead, it sure makes sense (and is an often mentioned pattern). But usually, to keep complexity low, both sets of values are combined into one single resource (your "Object" in this case).

Your paths are pretty good, Eric's version is also fine - here is my suggestion:

1. /rest/objects (all complete objects info)
2. /rest/objects/basic (all basic info)
3. /rest/objects/state (all state info)
4. /rest/objects/7 (single complete object)
5. /rest/objects/2/basic (single basic info)
6. /rest/objects/5/state (single state info)

In the end it all boils down to a matter of personal preference as the exact URL doesn't matter much.

See for instance http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/10/url-structures-and-hyper-media-for-web.html for a longer discussion on this issue (disclaimer: that's my blog).

Answer (score 0):

> resource/entity

Don't confuse these concepts. REST has nothing to do how you store your data, and resources map to entities only by CRUD applications.

> I read that evenry resource/entity should have its own, unique URL.

You should read the [IRI standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt). IRIs are for identifying resources. [Without them you cannot tell the server what you want to manipulate.](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2)

> However, I've some doubts pointed in 4 - it doesn't look like to be
>   correct. There are two ways to access the same
>   information/resource/entity.
>
> How to deal with it?

It is up to you. You can choose either of them or both. There is no restriction about how many identifiers a resource can have or what IRI structure to choose.